# Count distinct with left join query executing long time

Tags: mysql

I have about 140k raws in all these tables:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT p.product_id ) AS total
FROM bh_product p
LEFT JOIN bh_product_description pd ON ( p.product_id = pd.product_id ) 
LEFT JOIN bh_product_to_store p2s ON ( p.product_id = p2s.product_id )
```

Is it normal that execution of this query takes about 3 seconds?
All tables have indexes on product_id field.
Can it be somehow improved?

**UPDATED**:
Original query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT p.product_id ) AS total
FROM bh_product p
LEFT JOIN bh_product_description pd ON ( p.product_id = pd.product_id ) 
LEFT JOIN bh_product_to_store p2s ON ( p.product_id = p2s.product_id ) 
WHERE pd.language_id =  '2'
AND p.status =  '1'
AND p.date_available <= NOW( ) 
AND p2s.store_id =  '0'
AND (
pd.name LIKE  '%душевые%'
OR pd.tag LIKE  '%душевые%'
OR LCASE( p.model ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.sku ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.upc ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.ean ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.jan ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.isbn ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.mpn ) =  'душевые'
)
```

**UPDATED**: It figured out that the server were running other intensive process, that was slowing sql processing. 
After turning off other process perfomance become acceptable.

Comment: do you have index against `p.product_id` column?

Comment: @Alex yes, all tables have it indexed PRIMARY, BTREE

Comment: that is very weird schema why you need same `PRIMARY` key in 3 tables?

Comment: I dont know, these tables are made by opencart 
They all have product_id, maybe thats the reason why it is indexed.
`bh_product_description` 
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
`bh_product`
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
`bh_product_to_store`
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`store_id`)

Comment: so now you can see only 1 table `bh_product` has `PRIMARY KEY (product_id) ` all others have primary complex key `(product_id,language_id)` and `(product_id,store_id) `

Comment: So I need to add single product_id index to other 2 tables indexes?

Comment: not only... let me check something, and if you can provide sql fiddle with some data samples. that would help a lot.

Comment: I don't know how to use it(

Comment: tried to partial export via myadmin and insert into fiddle, it generate some error on Build Schema button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( 
  DISTINCT p.product_id ) AS total
FROM bh_product p
INNER JOIN bh_product_description pd 
ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
  AND pd.language_id = 2
INNER JOIN bh_product_to_store p2s 
ON p.product_id = p2s.product_id 
  AND p2s.store_id = 0
WHERE p.status =  '1'
AND p.date_available <= NOW( ) 
AND (
pd.name LIKE  '%душевые%'
OR pd.tag LIKE  '%душевые%'
OR 'душевые' IN ( p.model , p.sku , p.upc , p.ean , p.jan , p.isbn , p.mpn ))
```

But your most weak point here is your `WHERE` clause. you are trying to search everywhere. That is not very smart. I am pretty sure that `p.ean` is barcode and can't be equal to `душевые` same for `p.isbn`. So you should change your query to do only what you really need to do. But not filter everything with hope to "catch the fish".

**Update** Check this query (should be much faster then your 1st one):

```
SELECT COUNT( 
  DISTINCT p.product_id ) AS total
FROM bh_product p
INNER JOIN bh_product_description pd 
ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
  AND pd.language_id = 2
INNER JOIN bh_product_to_store p2s 
ON p.product_id = p2s.product_id 
  AND p2s.store_id = 0
```

Comment: ok, I understand a bit, but why does the simplest query without WHERE runs so slow?
"and I guess this one is pretty fast even if you are joining tables with no reason." 
The first query in my question runs 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `left join` your result will be same with

```
select count(distinct p.product_id) as total 
from bh_product p
```

because `left join` could filter nothing by your `product_id`.

Comment: I have additional filtering on joined tables, but the query that I showed in my question is test query. I don't understand why it takes so long time to execute.

Comment: so provide your real query, because this one is not very clever, and I guess this one is pretty fast even if you are joining tables with no reason.

Comment: If you really want to filter the data you need to use inner join.

Comment: This one takes 3 seconds

Comment: added to main question

Comment: This part will use no index and all rows be fetched. Try to use fulltext index (only for MyISAM engine) or use some search engines for your needs, like Sphinx or ElasticSearch.

AND (
pd.name LIKE  '%душевые%'
OR pd.tag LIKE  '%душевые%'
OR LCASE( p.model ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.sku ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.upc ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.ean ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.jan ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.isbn ) =  'душевые'
OR LCASE( p.mpn ) =  'душевые'
)

Answer (score -1):

I think You are trying to execute query like this

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT p.product_id ) AS total
FROM bh_product p ,bh_product_description pd,bh_product_to_store p2s where
 p.product_id = pd.product_id and p.product_id = p2s.product_id ;
```